# python, SSH: узнать параметры входа на локальную машину- username и host ip

Tags: python, ssh

Вопрос может быть максимально нубский. Но я че то не могу догнать как используя python получить параметры локальной машины для входа на нее через другую.

То есть я хочу подключиться к удаленной машине и перекинуть с локалки на нее файлы. Наоборот я уже научился, когда перекидываю файлы еще до подключения. А так че то не получается.

Вот что пробую что б получить юзера и имя машины.

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('USERNAME'))

import socket   
hostname=socket.gethostname()   
IPAddr=socket.gethostbyname(hostname)  
print(IPAddr)
```

вот команда которой пытаюсь перекидывать файлы (после подключения к удаленной машине):

```
scp <os.environ.get('USERNAME')>@<IPAddr>:<full path to file> <destination>
```

Вот что получаю по итогу:

```
ssh: connect to host <IPAddr> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Не понятно. Вы же пишите, что подключились к удаленной машине. Как вы это сделали?

Comment: не не, хост и юзера удаленное машины я знаю, я теперь пытаюсь переместить файлы с локалки. Я пытаюсь написать скрипт, который узнает хост и юзера на локалке

Comment: А чем, по-вашему, отличается хост и юзер на удаленной машине от хоста и юзера на локалке?

Comment: А зачем? `scp` этого не нужно знать. Если вы можете копировать файлы на удалённую машину, то и обратно тоже можете.